# Where's my Netmeeting on my Windows XP? conf doesn't work

Tags: windows-xp, netmeeting

I tried conf and it said command unrecognized. I am not sure if netmeeting was removed.

I can't find a link on Microsoft's site to install it. It says it's not available for XP. Their site mentions Netmeeting Space which I can't find. I need to use netmeeting to connect to another netmeeting at work.

Is there anyone who packaged Netmeeting to be installed on demand on XP? I mean how do you get it back?

Comment: I had this exact same question a few years ago. +1

Answer (score 2):

Netmeeting has been replaced with [Microsoft Office Live Meeting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/livemeeting/default.aspx)

Comment: I need to connect with someone who has netmeeting so I need to get netmeeting working on my machine again. I don't want to use replacements or other remote software. Does Mircosoft Office Live work with netmeeting?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't. Microsoft retired Netmeeting some time ago. The only thing I can suggest is to try or use another application like Skype or even MSN Messenger

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Netmeeting](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=26c9da7c-f778-4422-a6f4-efb8abba021e&displaylang=en) (will not install on XP

Edit:

How about [this](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/netmeet.htm):

> - Click Start, Run and type %Systemroot%\Inf
>
>   - Locate the file named msnetmtg.inf (Note that it may display as just msnetmtg if the Folder options is set to hide the extensions)
> - Right-click the msnetmtg.inf file, and choose Install
> - When you're prompted for the Windows XP CD-ROM, do any of the following:
>
>   1. Point the installer to %Systemroot%\i386 or %Systemroot%\ServicePackFiles\i386 folders, whichever location has the latest version of system files.
>   2. Insert your Windows XP CD-ROM into the drive. Note that if you've a Service Pack installed, you need the slipstreamed XP CD. If you don't have one, use method 1 above.

Comment: I tried that already. It doesn't install on XP. If you look at the supported list of Windows, XP is not there.

Comment: I can't find msnetmtg. Maybe it was removed so I can't reinstall Netmeeting

Answer (score 0):

try to go to [netmeeting.org](http://www.netmeeting.org/) it has all the links and help you need to get netmeeting running on xp. They have many different versions you can play with.\good luck